# PHP compare two equal strings failed

Tags: php, string, compare, strcmp

today i have a problem with two strings.
The first comes from an Function-Parameter, the second string i'm getting from a file.

I only see these characters: "703866200".

When i convert the two strings in ASCII-Chars, get this (I have the characters separated by dots):

> My Function-Param: 55.48.51.56.54.54.50.48.48
>
> String from File: 55.0.48.0.51.0.56.0.54.0.54.0.50.0.48.0.48

This means that the two strings are detected always different (strcmp).

Can anybody help me? - Is it an Encoding Problem, or what means that the second String is filled with zeros?

BTW, my string2ascii function:

```
function string_to_ascii($string){
    $ascii = NULL; 
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++){
      $ascii .= ".".ord($string[$i]);
    }
    return($ascii);
}
```

Comment: The string from file is a [double-byte character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBCS)

Comment: why your string from file is having 0(zero) after every .(dot) ?

Comment: I get the filecontent via "fopen" and "fgetcsv", how can i prevent the double-byte-encoding?

Comment: Can you give us base64 encoded contents of the file please?

Comment: I also tried this before my code:
        setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_CH.UTF-8');

When i read the file and write the content to a new file, i see some special chinese characters in the new document.

The source document is a Tab-seperated CSV-File...

Comment: I have just found out that the encoding is UTF-16.
Can the problem caused by this?